# Rails, How to delete an association in has_many through

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I Have a scenario, which I am not able to figure out,

```
Profile      Product
customer1    Iphone
customer2    Iphone
```

Now customer1 sells his iphone, so i will have to delete the association between customer1 and iphone but not the profile or product. I have an intermediate table for many to many relationship called `product_profiles` with `product_id` and `profile_id` as fields. Hence i need to delete id's from product_profiles table.

Product model

```
has_many :product_profiles
has_many :profiles, :through => :product_profiles
```

Profile model

```
has_many :product_profiles
has_many :products, :through => :product_profiles
```

Product controller

```
def destroy

    if ProductProfile.where(:product_id =>  params[:id]).where(:profile_id => ?).destroy //how to get the profile_id from view when clicked on delete button
      redirect_to admin_products_path
      flash[:success] = "Product Successfully Deleted!"
    else
      flash[:error] = "Sorry! Could not complete the request, please try again!"
      redirect_to :action => 'index'
   end  
 end
```

View file

```
<% @products.each do |b| %>
                <tr>
                    <td><%= @profile.name %></td> 

                    <td>
                    <% b.sub_categories.each do |p| %>
                        <%= p.name + ',' %>
                    <% end %>
                    </td>

                    <td><%= b.name %></td>
                    <td>
                    <%= link_to "<span class='glyphicon glyphicon-edit'></span>".html_safe,  edit_admin_product_path(b) %>
                   </td>
                   <td>
                    <%= link_to "<span class='glyphicon glyphicon-trash'></span>".html_safe, admin_product_path(b), :method => :delete, :title => "Delete Brand", "data-confirm" => "Do you really want to delete?" %>
                  </td>
                    </tr>
                <% end %>
```

Comment: Is it possible to just reset the product's foreign key id when you want to remove the association? To say -1?

Comment: I would really look at your relationships. If phone can only belong to one user perhaps there should be relationship one to many? so phone has id of owner.

Comment: products table can have many products not just phone, and users can own many products

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can pass parameters using the second argument of the path helper.

```
<%= link_to "<span class='glyphicon glyphicon-trash'></span>".html_safe, admin_product_path(b, :profile_id => @profile.id), :method => :delete, :title => "Delete Brand", "data-confirm" => "Do you really want to delete?" %>
```

In your controller you would then be able to access params[:profile_id]

Answer (score 3):

```
product = Product.find_by_id(product_id)
product.product_profiles.delete(product_profile_id)
```

Delete is not going to destroy your objects only the association between them.

Source:
http://neyric.com/2007/07/08/how-to-delete-a-many-to-many-association-with-rails/